# How to preserve html format of string stored in MongoDB

Tags: html, angularjs, mongodb, format

I'm currently using AngularJS as my frontend and mongodb as backend database. I use [textAngular](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular) for post edit. When I create a new post, say *service agreement*, the post comes with some formatting which is automatically implemented by wearing some html tags by textAngular, like

```
<p>hello world, this is just some test string</p>
<p>1. condition one</p>
<p>2. condition two</p>
<p>Contact:&nbsp;<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a></p>
```

I then store the post content that has all those html tags into Mongodb, and later, print out this post on another webpage, however the printed out version has all the html tags showing up instead of preserving the desired formatting... How can I achieve what I want? That is, to print out the content with original formatting, NOT the raw html tags?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I really should've dig a bit more, say $scope.postContent is the string that retrieved from mongodb that has the post content with html tags, answer is simple:

```
<div ng-bind-html="postContent"></div>
```

For Angular version lower than 1.2, you may wanna use

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="postContent"></div>
```

instead.